# Где хранятся скрытые значения у HTML элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В Элементе input:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

никакой цены нету, но при нажатии на (+) / (-) цена меняется. Вопрос: откуда берется цена выбранного элемента?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вы решили, что раз кнопка увеличивает какой-то счётчик, то она непременно должна хранить информацию о том, насколько счётчик должен увеличиться.

Позвольте опровергнуть это:

```js
increment = [50, 70, 20];
values = [90, 40, 30];

// заполнить все элементы начальными значениями

document.querySelectorAll("counter").forEach(function(counter, index){
  counter.innerHTML = values[index];
})

// добавить onclick всем элементам
document.querySelectorAll('btn').forEach(function(btn, index) {
   btn.onclick = function() {
    values[index] += increment[index];
    document.querySelectorAll("counter")[index].innerHTML = values[index];
  }
})
```

```css
btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>яблоки
  <counter>0</counter>
  <btn>+</btn>
</div>
<div>бананы
  <counter>0</counter>
  <btn>+</btn>
</div>
<div>персики
  <counter>0</counter>
  <btn>+</btn>
</div>
```

Вернёмся к вопросу. Ответ - может храниться где угодно в виде переменной в JavaScript или параметре любого другого тэга HTML.

Comment: Да но каким образом у radio button есть значение при клике на него

Comment: @Tand что значит каким образом? Посмотрите мой код: btn увеличивает counter на 50, но разве она хранит значение 50? Нажмите "выполнить код", чтобы понять, о чем я

Comment: Хорошо, а что если это динамический елемент и он может быть не один

Comment: @tand я отвечу, но сначала, может, вы и так сообразите. Позвольте вас спросить - вы заметили, где я храню значение 50 для увеличения счетчика?

Comment: в переменной increment

Comment: @tand правильно, а что мешает мне хранить, например, массив из переменных increment = [50, 100, 200], который содержит несколько счетчиков, и для каждого radio button получать свой счетчик?

Comment: @tand например, допустим у меня есть radioButton[0], для нее будет увеличитель increment[0], а ещё есть radioButton[1], для нее будет увеличитель increment[1]

Comment: Хорошо, а как вы будите вычитать сумму пред идущего выбранного елемента

Comment: @tand очень просто - смотрите, я могу получить текущее значение с помощью innerHML. Посмотрите, как это реализовано в коде в моем примере

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135365/discussion-between-tand-and-great-tech).